# IIS URL Rewrite with ColdFusion keeps duplicates string

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, coldfusion

I have set up a URL rewrite which works fine when I manually set or type in the URL. But when I use a link in the page within a `<cfoutput>` tag for example, the link duplicates the string.

I'm using ColdFusion 2016 with IIS 10

For example the URL is

`www.site.com/results.cfm?lang=1&categoryid=2&budegtid=all&typeid=all&propertyid=316`

and I want it outputted like

`www.site.com/properties/en/all/all/all/316`

it works but what seems to be happing when I set the link using... 
`<cfoutput>` using the query...

```
<cfif getProps.recordcount>
<cfoutput query = "getProps" startrow="#url.start#" maxrows="#perpage#">
<a href="property/#lang#/#category_id#/#budgetid#/#typeid#/#getProps.property_id#" id="listVewButton">View</a>
</cfoutput>
```

the result in the link on the page outputs as `www.site.com/properties/en/all/all/all/316/properties/en/all/all/all/316`

I have web/config set up as

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<configuration>  
<system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
    <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" />
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
<rule name="Property list URL rewrite">
   <match url="^property/([_0-9a-z-]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)/budget-range-([_0-9a-z-]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)" />
<action type="Rewrite" url="resultsproperty.cfm?lang={R:1}&amp;categoryid={R:2}&amp;budegtid={R:3}&amp;typeid={R:4}&amp;propertyid={R:5}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
</rules>
    </rewrite>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The ColdFusion cfquery is as follows...

```
<cfquery name="getProps" datasource="#session.odbcname#">
SELECT  *
FROM    properties P
INNER JOIN areas A
ON      A.area_id = P.property_areaid
INNER JOIN categories C
ON      C.category_id = P.property_propcategoryid
INNER JOIN  price R
ON      R.price_id = P.property_regularity
INNER JOIN types T
ON      T.type_id = P.property_proptypeid
WHERE   P.property_status != 'Off Market'
<cfif url.ref is not "all">
    AND     
        (
        property_ref like <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="%#url.ref#%">
        OR property_refid like  <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="%#url.ref#%">
        OR property_town like  <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="%#url.ref#%">
        )
</cfif>
ORDER   BY P.property_refid
```

It seems to be pulling in the actual URL first and then adding on the rewrite.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Read FRT to learn more https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: This is more likely to do with your CFOUTPUT. If they are nested wrong, they will duplicate the output. i.e in a cfoutput "loop" - show more of your CF code.

Comment: Hi, I have now updated the post and added in the CF code. Thanks

Comment: The url rewrite will not doing anything to the code. Inspect the link in the browser and see if you see the same URL. If its doubled in the inspection, then its got nothing to do with the URL Rewrite. Are you sure you do not have cfoutput tags inside that cfoutput loop?

Comment: Hi sorry, I have now added in the correct URL webconfig

Comment: Your rewrite rule requires that the string `budget-range-` is in there. But the CF code does not insert that string into the URL

Comment: Hi, I have placed various string for tests in there for testing but that particular string dose not affect the duplication of the URL

Answer (score 2):

You need to start the href with a forward slash to indicate it is from root. The href is resolved/interpretted in the browser. Not starting with a forward slash tells the browser that the url is relative to the current path.

If you are at `http://example.com/admin/` and have an href `logout` for example it will be resolved as `http://example.com/admin/logout`. However if you have an href `/logout` it will resolve to '`http://example.com/logout`.

As your own answer stated, forcing an absolute path works and can be preferred sometimes but sometimes not. Make sure you understand the underlying issue.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! by pre setting the URL root in the coldfusion application file i.e. `<cfset request.root = 'http://www.example.com/'>` and then reference the `#request.root#` var within the link, it uses the link correctly and dose not duplicate the url. So this is a cold fusion issue rather than a URL ReWrite issue.